# How to locate the element within an iframe using Selenium WebDriver through Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

While doing automation testing on this website http://www.scstrade.com/TechnicalAnalysis/tvchart/ i was unable to find the element using selenium.

i want to find the search bar element at the top which is used to search for stocks and then pass the name of desired stock in that bar using selenium.
Here is the xpath for the search bar :

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/input
```

here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\PyCharm Projects\Web Automation\drivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.scstrade.com/TechnicalAnalysis/tvchart/")
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/input')
Output : []
```

i also tried finding the element using the class name:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-3lfOzLDc-')
```

which gives me this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"input-3lfOzLDc-"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

The element i am trying to access only has the class name so i can't try using the id.
I also tried switching to the frame first but i can't even find the frame element for this website using selenium.

Comment: Looks like you have problem with locating the element. To get help with that, you should show us how HTML looks like. Or at least some piece from it.

Comment: give dom information and have you check dom structure in the browser which is launched by selenium(sometime dom is diffrent based on cookies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search bar element at the top left corner is within an `<iframe>` so to invoke `send_keys()` on the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()`.
- You can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='charting_library/static/en-tv-chart']")))
    index = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#header-toolbar-symbol-search input")))
    index.click()
    index.clear()
    index.send_keys("KSE 30")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'charting_library/static/en-tv-chart')]")))
    index = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='header-toolbar-symbol-search']//input")))
    index.click()
    index.clear()
    index.send_keys("KSE 30")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)